# Error in executing commands in NetBeans with Derby database connection

Tags: netbeans, database-connection, derby

I installed Apache Derby and successfully created and connected with a derby database on NetBeans. While I was trying to execute commands with NetBeans, I encountered an command error **even when my SQL command is correct in syntax**. What should I do to fix the problem?

Here's my code:
[image]

And here's the error message:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`show databases` is not a *SQL* command, it is an *ij* command. ij is a command line interpreter for working with Derby databases, and it accepts some extended syntax which is above and beyond SQL itself.

So you can only give a command like `show databases` to ij; you can't give it to any general-purpose SQL processing tool, like the Netbeans SQL tool. Those tools only understand SQL proper, not the IJ extensions

Here's some docs about ij:

- https://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.15/tools/ctoolsij34525.html
- https://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.15/tools/rtoolsijcomref25570.html

Comment: I see...I can still use commands like SELECT, UPDATE and DELETE, which are authentic SQL commands.